# What do the following words/phrases mean? (2)

Tags: translation

I’ve been wanting to do a barrel roll since I was eight. Imagine
I was a kid watching the AMC barrel roll in *The Man with the
Golden Gun*. I now know that jump was real, but **the car didn’t drive out.** Still, it was the best it could be back in the Seventies. If they’d not done that, I wouldn’t have just done the best barrel roll in the world ever.

...

Gary Powell and Lee Morrison are my stunt coordinators. We’ve
all known each other for years and they’re the best, **they work on Bond**.

...

I had to get in a car and start jumping it. The first six jumps were into the air bags. Eventually I had to go for it. The first jump I’d landed but then **flipped over onto my roof.**

...

I probably jumped that jump a dozen times and landed on the wheels maybe six times. The rest have been rollovers or **nose-to-tail** or ended upside down.

---

I've looked them up in the dictionary and googled them when necessary.
I understand them to mean the following:

**the car didn’t drive out** => the car didn't move

**they work on Bond** => they work closely together

**flipped over onto my roof** => The roof hit him on the head (basically the car turned upside-down)

**nose-to-tail** => (the car's front) crushing with the landing ramp.

---

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Bond. James Bond. They're the best, they work in James Bond movies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks four questions not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the car didn’t drive out

The car was not capable of being driven after the stunt.

> they work on Bond

They work on James Bond films. The fact that 'Bond' is capitalised should tell you it is a name rather than something that binds.

> flipped over onto my roof

When he says 'my roof' he means the roof of the car he was driving. The car *did* end up upside down, but the driver's head isn't referred to.

> nose-to-tail

I'm less certain on this but think it means the car landed (he's talking about the different outcomes of performing jumps with the car) on it's front bumper and then bounced and pitched such that it then lands in its rear bumper. I can't be sure if it means it lands at an oblique angle to its direction of travel and bounces backward or it lands an an acute angle and tumbles forward as it bounces. This phrase probably qualifies as jargon and would be understood by the stunt-driving community.

Comment: +1. On *nose-to-tail*, it's probably a forward tumble - it seems very unlikely for that much momentum to reverse so quickly. Here's a reference to consider adding to your answer: *The nose of the truck just kept rising and rising and rising. I lost the ramp on the other side—couldn’t see it at all—I was looking at blue sky.” The truck landed tail-first and the force of the impact whipped the nose of the truck down so hard it bent the frame and blew out the windshield and rear window."* - [Hal Needham’s Six Greatest Stunts](https://stuntsunlimited.com/founder/hal-needhams-six-greatest-stunts/)

Comment: @Lawrence Thank you for the suggestion and the +1. I won't add that though, as it describes a truck that lands tail first and doesn't mention landing on the nose at all. Cars for stunts will be weighted to achieve a desired effect and hence may not behave in a very 'natural' way, but I agree the forward tumble may be more likely.